# Changing the players sprite with animator

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a 2d platformer with a player. The players default sprite is set to idle. There is 4 sprites and states in total --> idle, jumping, left, right.

Im trying to get the player to switch sprites depending on what their doing eg jumping or moving right.

This is my first time using unity and animator so im not experienced at all.

So each of my animations look something like this. 1 frame and one for each state:

[image]

And then I open up the animator:

[image]

Im not too sure what the arrows do but i figured its like a flow chart so you go from idle to left so i matched up the arrows. I then also made 4 booleans for each state.

Then on the script attached to the player, i added this code:

```
private Animator animator;

    void Start () {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    //This is in the update function
    if (!playerLeft && !playerRight && !jumping)
        {
            setAnimationState("playerIdle");
        }
        else if (jumping)
        {
            setAnimationState("playerJumping");
        }
    }

    private void setAnimationState(String state){
        animator.SetBool("playerJumping", false);
        animator.SetBool("playerLeft", false);
        animator.SetBool("playerRight", false);
        animator.SetBool("playerIdle", false);
        animator.SetBool(state, true);
    }
```

So i made a function that cancels of the animations and switches it to the correct one which is called. You can see how i call it with jumping and i also have the same for left and right but i know they are all being called correctly from the animator.

In the animator, only the right grey box is running. I can see because it has a blue bar and its not switching animations. The booleans are switching but thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top of my head:

You need a transition from right to left and left to right.
You need one from right, left and jumping back to idle.

You can click on the arrows and select which booleans need to be checked to enable the transition.

Fore each animation state you need to upload a spritesheet. You can drag and drop this in the animation tab. The animation will play untill there are no more sprites.  It will then check if it can transition into another state or loop the current state. (Do note that you need to enable looping on each state, except jumping i guess?)

Comment: ohh i totally get why the arrows are there now, i fixed it. Ive pretty much put and arrow from each state to every state. So instead of going from right to idle to left, the player just goes from right to left. Same with jumping, thanks :D

Comment: Glad i could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Unity development :)

I don't want to make this too long, so let's just use playerLeft as an example.

So you've set the Idle state as the default state - meaning if all the booleans are false, the player is idle. But once you press the left key, you would want the player to *transition* from the idle state to the Left state.

**First step** is to click on the transition (the arrow) from idle to playerLeft.

**Next,** is to add the *playerLeft* boolean as the condition. This means that when the *playerLeft* boolean becomes true, we start transitioning from Idle to Left.

**And finally,** tinker with the code. We need to tell Unity to set playerLeft to true when we press the "D" button for example.

```
Update()  
{
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) 
     animator.SetBool("playerLeft",true); 
}
```

We place it in the Update() method to make sure it runs every frame. Then, we have a condition where it waits for the player to press D.

There's still a whole lot to do after this such as doing return transitions but well, you'll figure out the rest as you go so don't hesitate to ask ;)

Comment: Thanks daniels, i just finished doing it before you posted this, all i was missing was the arrows and the conditions which ive fixed. It seems theres a tiny bit of lag when switching animations even you it goes from one state to another with nothing inbetween. Hopefully that will sort itself out when i package it to an .exe, Thank you though :D